# Increase map zoom doesn't work after fitBounds call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I don't know why this doesn't seem to work. I want the map to have the bounds set according to a circle's bounds but it doesn't zoom in enough and there is way too much padding, so I try an increase in zoom after fitBounds and it does nothing.

???

LatLngD and LatLngO are global and are set elsewhere.

```
function initializeMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: LatLngO,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: false
    });
    setRadius();
}

function setRadius() {
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(LatLngO, LatLngD);
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: LatLngO,
        radius: distance,
    });
    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 is event based. You need to wait until the new zoom level takes effect before incrementing it by one.

```
map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
});
```

(The `addListenerOnce` performs the action once, then removes the event listener)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3w91bq4e/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var LatLngO = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72);
var LatLngD = new google.maps.LatLng(42.5, -72.7);

function initializeMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: LatLngO,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: false
  });
  setRadius();
}

function setRadius() {
  var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(LatLngO, LatLngD);
  circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: LatLngO,
    radius: distance,
  });
  map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using the `idle` event which is called after the map has initialized and set its bounds properly:

```
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});
```

Comment: That does work, and fortunately I only want it to increase by one on initial load, as the map won't continually resize as the radius does and the radius will always reduce, But I still don't understand why what I had doesn't work. If nobody has any other suggestions in the next hour, I'll mark it as answered because it does work in my explained situation.